# What is MongeElkan distance between words?

Tags: reference-request, strings, string-metrics

i used `CosineSimilarity`, `EuclideanSimilarity`, `LevenshteinSimilarity` and known about how it calculates the distance between two words. Can anyone explain how `MongeElkan` distance calculates the similarity.